# Determinar o número de itens duma lista que se encontram dentro dos limites definidos noutra lista

Tags: c#, lista

Tenho uma `ListBox` que contem um valor indeterminado de valores e quero jogar esses valores para uma `List<>` e pelo que pesquisei, consegui fazer até aqui:

```
var todosValores = lstRoll.Items.OfType<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
List<double> listaDeNums = todosValores.Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToList();

var lista = new List<double>();
lista.Add(somaLinha1);
lista.Add(Math.Round((somaLinha1 + valorTamanhoIntervalo), 2));
```

O código acima joga os valores da `ListBox` pra uma `List<>` e depois joga pra uma outra `List<>` convertendo pra `double` os valores. Acontece que agora tenho uma outra `List` distinta dessas que contém números decimais.

Supondo que a minha `listaDeNums` agora carregue os valores `{ 1,2,3,...,9,10 }` e a minha **outra lista** (variável `lista` no código) carregue os valores `{ 2.86 , 5.65 }`.

Esses dois valores precisam ser tratados como o início e fim de um intervalo que serão interseccionados na `listaDeNums` e uma variável seja incrementada a cada número que faça parte da interseção.

Neste caso concreto exemplificado por mim acima a minha variável incrementada no final, deveria dar ***3*** porque entre ***2.86*** e ***5.65*** numa lista de **1** a **10** existe 3 números.

Comment: ta complicado entender o que precisa fazer? tem algum exemplo minimo para colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: Exatamente o que Ramaral postou, o segundo bloco de código dele quase me atendeu xD

Answer (score 2):

Se na "outra lista" o item 0 é o limite inferior e o item 1 o limite superior, o código abaixo constrói uma lista com os valores que se encontram dentro desses limites.

```
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var limites = new List<double>{ 2.86, 5.65 };

var ocurrencias = new List<int>();
ocurrencias = lista.Where(valor => valor >= limites[0] && valor <= limites[1]).ToList();
```

Se quiser saber apenas o numero de itens da lista que se encontram no intervalo use:

```
var lista = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var limites = new List<double>{ 2.86, 5.65 };
var numeroDeOcurrencias = lista.Count(valor => valor >= limites[0] && valor <= limites[1]);
```

Veja no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FtxMlL).

Comment: Olá Ramaral!
A segunda linha de código quase me atendeu... O problema é que está considerando um intervalo aberto, e eu preciso do intervalo fechado, porque supondo que os meus limites fossem de 1 à 3,26 o 1 também contaria na quantidade de intersecções... Desse jeito, está acontecendo o seguinte: https://puu.sh/zPh0x/cd07103a9e.png

Na segunda linha, também, o resultado também deveria ser 3, porque de 3,67 até 6,34 há 3 números na lista (4,5,6)

Comment: Confira o seu código pois o intervalo é fechado. Veja que estou usando `>=` e `<=`.